# Why does position of -C matter in git commands?

Tags: git, arguments, options

The following works:

```
git -C ~/dotfiles status
```

But this fails:

```
git status -C ~/dotfiles
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because `-C` is a *global* option, and doesn't "belong" to the `status` action. This is a common pattern, resulting in synopses like the one below:

```
command [global options] action [action-specific options]
```

`git --help` lists Git's global options, and `man git` goes into more detail.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that every program defines its own option syntax, so this shouldn't be taken as a universal rule about options. Some of them can be moved around freely, some can only appear in certain places in the command line, and some can only show up in a specific order or a specific position.

Comment: And these decisions are often made by the library a program uses to parse its arguments. For example, GNU `ls` (using GNU `getopts`) treats `-` in `ls foo -l` as the long output option. BSD `ls` (using a different library), on the other hand, treats it as a filename argument.

Comment: @DavidZ well, kind of, at least for the standard UNIX tools it is standardized that options go before arguments in POSIX (with some exceptions). So, in general, it's likely that programs support at least that, although many GNU tools also allow options after arguments (as well as long opts, etc.)

Comment: @ljrk Yeah, but there are also things like `git status -u` which can't be flipped around to `git -u status`. And I figure a person who would ask this question might not be too familiar with command-line argument conventions in general, and so if they see something like `du -s dir/ -h` (GNU `du` of course) they might try to extract more meaning from that argument ordering than there really is. I just think it's easy to see one pattern or a few examples from one program and think all others work the same way, which is why I'd favor making the point that it really is up to the program.

Comment: @DavidZ Yeah it is, this wasn't meant as a critique, just an addendum :)

Comment: I was expecting the answer to be what @DavidZ says and was surprised at the upvotes. But this has taught me the distinction between global vs specific arguments concept of git, so I think it's a useful question. Git is not some arbitrary hack thrown together without thought; it has become the de facto standard and learning its logic is warranted IMO.

Comment: @DavidZ Re your 2nd remark: "The person who asks this question" of course understands that not all developers are capable of following a coherent interface. Git is an exception because it is orders of magnitude more complex than most other programs.